Estimating IMU biases without using any external aid
Assuming that Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) contains accelerometer and gyroscope, I want to estimate the bias in each of the sensors. We know that accelerometer and gyroscope have biases which change over time i.e. every time we start the IMU, initial bias is different and as time increases, the bias changes. In most of the cases, this bias is modeled as time integral of the Gaussian white noise i.e.:
\begin{equation}
 \dot{\mathbf{b}}_g = \boldsymbol\eta_g \hspace{30pt} \boldsymbol\eta_g \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \mathbf{Q}_g\right)\\
 \dot{\mathbf{b}}_a = \boldsymbol\eta_a \hspace{30pt} \boldsymbol\eta_a \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \mathbf{Q}_a\right) \\
\end{equation}
where, $\mathbf{b}_g$ and $\mathbf{b}_a$ are biases in gyroscope and accelerometer , respectively. Such modeling is common in navigation (ref: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1642588 eqns $(38b)$ and $(39 b)$ ) My questions are:

Can we estimate these biases by just using these two sensors? I do not mean the static bias which is constant, but the bias which is modeled above.
If we include magnetometer without any bias or use any other external aid, can we estimate the biases mentioned above?

